# bootstrap vertical menu ( with sub nav ) to be horizontal in small devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a vertical navigation menu with subitems.  I want the same to be horizontaol when it is viewd in small devices.  See below the images to get an idea.

[image]
Verical Menu

[image] What I need in small resolution

Comment: Have you ever try something ? Can you share some code ?

Comment: I tried this http://www.jonathanbriehl.com/2014/01/17/vertical-menu-for-bootstrap-3/ but I am not able to add subitems to menu item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires a custom implementation. Bootstrap 3 has removed submenus, but here's an example that may help you get started..

http://www.bootply.com/121902